# Webpack 2 refusing to ignore lovell/sharp in node_modules folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to create an app in Electron which uses React, Webpack 2 Sharp and Electron.

I just added Sharp (https://github.com/lovell/sharp) and Webpack is adamantly trying to build Sharp but I don't think it should be (I could be wrong and if so, how would I get these files to load)?

**I get the following stdout:**

```
WARNING in ./~/sharp/lib/constructor.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../vendor/lib/versions.json' in '/Users/andy/Development/image-browser/node_modules/sharp/lib'
@ ./~/sharp/lib/constructor.js 23:15-53
@ ./~/sharp/lib/index.js
@ ./app/src/utils/getImage.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/image.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/index.js
@ ./app/src/App.js
@ ./app/src/entry.js

WARNING in ./~/sharp/lib/icc/sRGB.icc
Module parse failed: /Users/andy/Development/image-browser/node_modules/sharp/lib/icc/sRGB.icc Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
@ ./~/sharp/lib ^\.\/.*$
@ ./~/sharp/lib/index.js
@ ./app/src/utils/getImage.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/image.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/index.js
@ ./app/src/App.js
@ ./app/src/entry.js

WARNING in ./~/sharp/lib/icc/cmyk.icm
Module parse failed: /Users/andy/Development/image-browser/node_modules/sharp/lib/icc/cmyk.icm Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
@ ./~/sharp/lib ^\.\/.*$
@ ./~/sharp/lib/index.js
@ ./app/src/utils/getImage.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/image.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/index.js
@ ./app/src/App.js
@ ./app/src/entry.js

ERROR in ./~/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node
Module parse failed: /Users/andy/Development/image-browser/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
@ ./~/sharp/lib/constructor.js 8:14-52
@ ./~/sharp/lib/index.js
@ ./app/src/utils/getImage.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/image.js
@ ./app/src/components/Images/index.js
@ ./app/src/App.js
@ ./app/src/entry.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {

    watch: true,

    target: 'electron',

    entry: './app/src/entry.js',

    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app/build',
        publicPath: 'build/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: /\/app\/src/,
                // exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            'env',
                            'react'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.node$/,
            //     use: {
            //         loader: 'node-loader'
            //     }
            // },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                include: /\/app\/src/,
                // exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                include: /\/app\/src/,
                // exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    query: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

**My babel config (extracted from package.json):**

```
"babel": {
    "retainLines": true,
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
            "targets": {
                "electron": 1.6,
                "node": 7.9
            },
                "modules": false,
                "debug": true
            }
        ],
        "es2015",
        "es2016",
        "es2017"
    ]
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/794

Comment: Hi, How did you solve this issue. Can you answer here please.

Comment: Hey, yes, good point. I will post the answer here later but to get you going if you need this information now, please refer to this comment: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/794#issuecomment-313762020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully got this working and the following is a mirror of the comment I added to this Github issue: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/794

The key was finding this article: http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I#p28 (thanks @jlongster).

My webpack.config.js looks like the following:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// FROM: http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I#p28
const nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(item => ['.bin'].indexOf(item) === -1)  // exclude the .bin folder
    .forEach((mod) => {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    target: 'electron',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/src/entry.js'],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: nodeModules,
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app/build',
        publicPath: 'build/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            'env',
                            'react'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src'),
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    query: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

**TL;DR**

Use this to get a list of ALL your node modules:

```
const nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(item => ['.bin'].indexOf(item) === -1 )  // exclude the .bin folder
    .forEach((mod) => {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });
```

and hand the nodeModules variable to Webpack's externals key:

```
externals: nodeModules,
```

Alternatively, you could use one of the Ignore Module Webpack plugins but I have not tried that myself.

Comment: It's worth simplifying that the actual root fix was simply using `externals: { sharp: 'commonjs sharp', ... }` to tell the webpack externals not just that sharp is something that shouldn't be bundled but with the commonjs qualifier. that's the ticket that makes this work properly with `externals`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got some luck with `node-loader` installed and set the following in the `package.json`

```
{
  test: /\.node$/,
  use: 'node-loader'
},
```

I solved the `ERROR in ./~/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node`. But I'm not sure if not solving the other three warnings will cause any issues yet.
But at least now my Electron application can be started now.